# I have a directory path, (~/.factorio/mods) how do I access this folder in order to copy a ZIP file into it?

Tags: files

Ive been driving myself mad trying to find this, its probably obvious but i cannot find the solution. I want to open the folder in the GUI in order to add a ZIP file to it. The path for mods in Linux is (~/.factorio/mods). I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

You are not seeing the `.factorio` directory because it is invisible. That is because it starts with a `.`.

Simply navigate to your home directory and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>. This will toggle invisible items on and off.